# c++ Alias for an array element

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, alias

I have a (column) Vector class which contains an array of values that can be accessed like:

```
Vec<int, 4> v();
v[0] = -2; // <- set first value to -2
v[1] = 1; // <- set second value to 1
....
```

But here is my question: How do i create an alias for `v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3]`?. I would like to define the first 4 values as `v.x, v.y, v.z, v.w`:

```
Vec<int, 4> v();
v.x = -2; // <- set first value to -2
v.y = 1; // <- set second value to 1
v.z = 4; // <- set third value to 4
v.w = 2; // <- set fourth value to 2
```

I should be able to **assign** and **read** the values, and I don't want them to be looking like a function, so accessing the first value like:

```
Vec<int, 4> v();
v.x() = -2; // <- set first value to -2
```

Is no good. On top of that the vector class is templated and x should only be defined for `dimensions >= 1`, and y only for `dimenions >= 2` ... and so on... How do I achieve this?

**Edit:** The Vector class has nothing to do with std::vector, it is a mathematical vector resembling an array, in that it is of fixed size and its only used for mathematical operations. (renaming Vector to Vec).

## What I have tried:

Matrix class:

```
template <typename T, size_t ROWS, size_t COLS>
class Matrix {

    public:
        T& operator[] (size_t idx) {return m_matrix[idx];}
        T operator[] (size_t idx) const {return m_matrix[idx];}

    private:
        m_matrix[ROWS * COLS]
};
```

Vector class:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
class Vec: public Matrix<T, 1, N>{

    public:

        T& x() {return (*this)[0];}
        T x() const {return (*this)[0];}

        T& y() {return (*this)[1];}
        T y() const {return (*this)[1];}

        T& z() {return (*this)[2];}
        T z() const {return (*this)[2];}

        T& w() {return (*this)[3];}
        T w() const {return (*this)[3];}
};
```

This works and I am easily able to use enable_if to remove the functions if it is not defined for this dimension, this however isn't syntactically pleasing. Ive tried using references:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
class Vec: public Matrix<T, N, 1>{

    public:

        T& x = (*this)[0];
        T& y = (*this)[1];
        T& z = (*this)[2];
        T& w = (*this)[3];
};
```

But this doesn't work, it doesn't give me an error, but it also does not set the values correctly, when I access them after setting they are undefined.

**Edit nr 2:** there might just exist an even simpler solution, when my last attempt with references is compiled using Visual Studio community 2015's default compiler, then it works. But when I compile it in Code::Blocks using the GNU GCC compiler, then it doesn't. What does the standard say? Is my solution using references allowed, which compiler is wrong?

Comment: You can define x, y, z and w explicitly in the class and override the square brackets operators to return x, y, z or w depending on the number/index given

Comment: why not use a wrapper for the vector

Comment: @JoshKisb yes but with that trick you can't assign something to v.x and copy the value to the internal vector [0].

Comment: `Vector<int, 4> v();` declares a function names `v` with no arguments and that returns a `Vector<int, 4>`.

Comment: The last attempt idea with the references was the right way I think, but your syntax is wrong

Comment: Completely unclear what is your goal. Array access is indexed, why do you need member variable access for it?

Comment: If all of the clients using this code know what a `Vector<int, 4> v;` is, why would you introduce another unknown syntax on them to now have to learn?  They would know quite well that `v` is accessed via array indexing, not by using `.x` or `.y`, etc.

Comment: I suggest you read how to emulate properties in C++ using unnamed classes (like C# property syntax): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_%28programming%29#C++

Comment: For clarity: The Vector class has nothing to do with std::vector it is a mathematical vector of fixed size that is used for performing math, I just didn't include a lot of the methods for simplicity

Comment: @SergeyA & PaulMcKenzie in some contexts (eg.math,graphics) vectors have idiomatic naming for the first few dimensions (xyzw,rgba,uvst...); when supported (eg. Eigen fixed vectors .x() accessors, glsl swizzles,...) they do improve code readability and usability over bare indices IMO ...

Comment: You can check glm library, which does exactly that for it's glm::vec class. They have alias for xyzw, rgba, uvst... https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/glm/detail/type_vec4.hpp

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
template <typename T, int D> struct Vec;

// You have to manually specialize for all needed sizes
template <typename T> struct Vec<T, 4>
{
    T x, y, z, w;

    T &operator[](int index)
    {
        switch (index)
        {
            default: // throw or something?
            case 0: return x;
            case 1: return y;
            case 2: return z;
            case 3: return w;
        }
    }
    const T &operator[](int index) const
    {
        switch (index)
        {
            default: // throw or something?
            case 0: return x;
            case 1: return y;
            case 2: return z;
            case 3: return w;
        }
    }
};
```

The `switch`ing on index is not optimal, but at least it's well-defined.

For matrices I prefer to use `Vec<Vec<T, Height>, Width>`, which makes `mat[x][y]` notation work. (Swap `x` and `y` if you want to.)

Comment: That's basically what I suggested, but rather than using a switch I was using  some not well-defined pointer arithmetic. And in a comment on my answer someone mentions using a switch. So not sure why you said it wasn't suggested yet :)

Comment: @oisyn Didn't notice that comment first. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you accept a C++14 solution, I propose the creation of a template indexed wrapper for `x`, `y`, `z` and `w`, referenced to `T` variables

```
template <typename T, std::size_t>
struct wrapper
 { wrapper (T const &) {} };

template <typename T>
struct wrapper<T, 0U>
 { T & x; };

template <typename T>
struct wrapper<T, 1U>
 { T & y; };

template <typename T>
struct wrapper<T, 2U>
 { T & z; };

template <typename T>
struct wrapper<T, 3U>
 { T & w; };
```

Next an `std::array` wrapper that has to be inherited **before** the indexed wrappers

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct arrayWrp
 { std::array<T, N> arr {}; };
```

Now you can define an helper `struct VecH` as follows

```
template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
struct VecH<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
   : public arrayWrp<T, sizeof...(Is)>, public wrapper<T, Is>...
 {
   using arrayWrp<T, sizeof...(Is)>::arr;

   VecH () : arrayWrp<T, sizeof...(Is)>{}, wrapper<T, Is>{ arr[Is] }...
    { }

   T & operator[] (std::size_t i)
    { return arr[i]; }

   T const & operator[] (std::size_t i) const
    { return arr[i]; }
 };
```

that inherit from `arrayWrp` and from all `wrapper<T, Is>` needed and that link references `x`, `y`, `z` and `w` to `arr[0]`, `arr[1]`, `arr[2]` and `arr[3]` rispectively

So `Vec` become

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct Vec : public VecH<T, std::make_index_sequence<N>>
 { };
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, std::size_t>
struct wrapper
 { wrapper (T const &) {} };

template <typename T>
struct wrapper<T, 0U>
 { T & x; };

template <typename T>
struct wrapper<T, 1U>
 { T & y; };

template <typename T>
struct wrapper<T, 2U>
 { T & z; };

template <typename T>
struct wrapper<T, 3U>
 { T & w; };

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct arrayWrp
 { std::array<T, N> arr {}; };

template <typename, typename>
struct VecH;

template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
struct VecH<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
   : public arrayWrp<T, sizeof...(Is)>, public wrapper<T, Is>...
 {
   using arrayWrp<T, sizeof...(Is)>::arr;

   VecH () : arrayWrp<T, sizeof...(Is)>{}, wrapper<T, Is>{ arr[Is] }...
    { }

   T & operator[] (std::size_t i)
    { return arr[i]; }

   T const & operator[] (std::size_t i) const
    { return arr[i]; }
 };

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct Vec : public VecH<T, std::make_index_sequence<N>>
 { };

int main ()
 { 
   Vec<int, 4U>  v4;

   v4.x = 1;
   v4.y = 2;
   v4.z = 3;
   v4.w = 4;

   std::cout << "v4: ";

   for ( auto ui = 0U ; ui < 4U ; ++ui )
      std::cout << ' ' << v4[ui];

   std::cout << std::endl;

   Vec<int, 5U>  v5;  // also over 4

   Vec<int, 3U>  v3;

   v3.x = 10;
   v3.y = 20;
   v3.z = 30;
   // v3.w = 40;  // compilation error

 }
```

If you don't like the use of the `VecH` helper `struct`, you can use partial specialization and a template parameter defaulted to `std::make_index_sequence<N>` as follows

```
template <typename, std::size_t N, typename = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct Vec;

template <typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Is>
struct Vec<T, N, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
   : public arrayWrp<T, N>, public wrapper<T, Is>...
 {
   using arrayWrp<T, sizeof...(Is)>::arr;

   Vec () : arrayWrp<T, sizeof...(Is)>{}, wrapper<T, Is>{ arr[Is] }...
    { }

   T & operator[] (std::size_t i)
    { return arr[i]; }

   T const & operator[] (std::size_t i) const
    { return arr[i]; }
 };
```

but I don't know if it's a good idea: someone could try to use `Vec` as follows

```
Vec<int, 3U, std::index_sequence<0, 2, 5>>  v;
```

Comment: A similar answer had been posted before (but less generic) which has already been deleted. The issue with references is that it makes the object needlessly big as every reference effectively stores a pointer. This also means that accessing such a member dereferences such a pointer. Also, it is no longer copyable by default.

Comment: @oisyn - given the unusual problem, I don't see the bigger size of the struct or the overhead dereferencing a pointer as a great problem. I know that you have proposed a smaller (and, in a sense, intriguing, IMHO) solution; but (as far I understand) is UB so (ever IMHO) I think my solution maintain a sort of interest. Anyway you're right about the copyable part: it's a problem. I have to explain this in my answer. Thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 1):

A completely different way would be to overload the bracket operator or – much simpler – use namespaces and defined constants:

```
namespace xyzw {
   constexpr const size_t X = 0;
   constexpr const size_t Y = 1;
   constexpr const size_t Z = 2;
   constexpr const size_t W = 3;
}

namespace rgba {
   constexpr const size_t R = 0;
   constexpr const size_t G = 1;
   constexpr const size_t B = 2;
   constexpr const size_t A = 3;
}
```

Now, you can use it in the way:

```
template<class V>
typename V::value_type snorm3(const V & v) {
  using namespace xyzw;
  if (v[W] == 0) return 0;
  return (v[X] * v[X] + v[Y] * v[Y] + v[Z] * v[Z]) / (v[W] * v[W]);
}

int test() {
  std::vector <int> t{ 0,1,2,3 };
  return snorm3 (t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an untested extension @max66 we could define the wrapper in a dfferent way:

```
template <typename T, size_t n, class V = std::vector<T> >
class wrapper {
  wrapper(V & vec):v(vec) {}
  operator T & () { return v[n]; }
  operator = (const T & o) { v[n] = o; }
protcted:
   V & v;
}

template <typename T, class V = std::vector<T> > 
class Vec: public V {
public:
  wrapper<T,0,V> x;
  wrapper<T,1,V> y;
  wrapper<T,2,V> z;
  wrapper<T,3,V> w;
  Vec(): x(*this), y(*this), z(*this), w(*this) {} 
}
```

Here, the wrapper references the vector (or whatever is used) and indexes at access times. This could be slower and since x, y, z, w are not values but wrappers around them you may have to define more operators for them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this, assuming `Vec<T>::operator[]()` returns `T&` and assuming elements in the `Vec` are located sequentially in the memory:

```cpp
struct XYZW {
  int x, y, z, w;
};

Vec<int, 4> v;
v[0] = 1;
v[1] = 2;
v[2] = 3;
v[3] = 4;


auto p = reinterpret_cast<XYZW*>(&v[0]);

// use it:
std::cout << p->x << ',' << p->y << ',' << p->z << ',' << p->w << std::endl;

// compare with Vec:
std::cout << v[0] << ',' << v[1] << ',' << v[2] << ',' << v[3] << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is too late for you, but anyways there will be someone else searching for a solution.

I think something like this fulfils you're wish:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct vec {
  static_assert(N <= 4, "Dimension of vec must be 4 or less.");

  struct EmptyType {};
  using T1 = typename std::conditional_t<N >= 1, T, EmptyType>;
  using T2 = typename std::conditional_t<N >= 2, T, EmptyType>;
  using T3 = typename std::conditional_t<N >= 3, T, EmptyType>;
  using T4 = typename std::conditional_t<N >= 4, T, EmptyType>;

  union {
    struct {
      T1 x;
      T2 y;
      T3 z;
      T4 w;
    };
    std::array<T, N> data;
  };

  vec(const std::array<T, N>& data):
    this->data(data) {} 

  // ...
};
```

The positions in the union are the same as in the array, so [0] is x and so on.

Tested on VS v17.8-preview.1 with c++ latest.

Answer (score -3):

You could do something like:

```
// General case uses an array
template<class T, std::size_t N>
class VectorData
{
private:
    T m_data[N];

public:
    T& operator[](int i) { return m_data[i]; }
    const T& operator[](int i) const { return m_data[i]; }
};

// Specializations for various N (4 shown here)
template<class T>
class VectorData<T, 4>
{
public:
    T x, y, z, w;

    T& operator[](int i) { return (&x)[i]; }  // WARNING, see note below
    const T& operator[](int i) const { return (&x)[i]; }
};


template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct Vector : public VectorData<T, N>
{
    // your other Vector stuff here
};
```

**Note**: As one of the commenters below correctly pointed out, this assumes that array elements are layed out in memory exactly the same as a list of variables (iow, `T[4]` and `struct { T x,y,z,w; }` are layout-compatible) for the `&x[i]` part to work. The standard doesn't guarantee this, and therefore this code will yield undefined behavior. In practice this is fine and doing it this way is way more performant. If you need a portable, standard compliant implementation, you could opt to use a `switch` within `VectorData::operator[]`, as another answer suggested. The difference in code generated can be seen [here](https://godbolt.org/g/Hn3bb3).

If you really need Vector to derive from Matrix, something like this is still possible. The general idea is just that you decouple storage and functionality. You could create some generic Matrix class with all functionality, which has an extra template parameter for its storage. A Vector could then just supply its own storage type.

Something like:

```
// Generic matrix storage
template<class T, std::size_t N>
class MatrixData
{
private:
    T m_data[N];

public:
    T& operator[](int i) { return m_data[i]; }
    const T& operator[](int i) const { return m_data[i]; }
};

// Generic matrix class
template<class T, std::size_t ROWS, std::size_t COLS, class Storage = MatrixData<T, ROWS*COLS>>
class Matrix : public Storage
{
    // Matrix functionality here
};



// Specialized storage for Vectors, generic version
template<class T, std::size_t N>
class VectorData : public MatrixData<T, N> { };

// Specialized storage for Vector<T, 4>
template<class T>
class VectorData<T, 4>
{
public:
    T x, y, z, w;

    T& operator[](int i) { return (&x)[i]; }
    const T& operator[](int i) const { return (&x)[i]; }
};

template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct Vector : public Matrix<T, N, 1, VectorData<T, N>>
{
    // your other stuff here
};
```

Comment: `return (&x)[i]` is UB for i greater than 0. You can only use pointer arithmetic within arrays. Using a `switch` block would work though.

Comment: @Bathsheba Are you sure? Isn't an array layout-compatible with a struct containing the same elements as different variables?

Comment: I'm absolutely certain of this.

Comment: @Bathsheba Well in that case, the code certainly isn't portible, but it'll still work on all major well-know platforms.

Comment: Looking very good it just takes some time for me to implement it, if it works I  accept it :)
But looking at it should!

Comment: @JensModvig I've edited my post. Bathsheba is correct in pointing out that this might not work on your implementation as expected. Although I would be very surprised if you managed to find a commonly used platform on which this doesn't work, it is something to be aware of :).

Comment: @oisyn I noticed, even before you edited the code ;) But ye, it is still the best answer, not optimal but very good

Comment: @oisyn After going through about 1000 lines of code I finally got it implemented and it works like a charm, thank you very much, does exactly what I requested :)

Comment: "In practice this is fine and doing it this way is way more performant." It is **not** fine. It might appear to work for you but it is UB and you're liable to get unwanted behaviour at some point, it might "work" 99% of the time but give a mysterious and hard-to-debug problem the other 1%, it might appear to work but stop working when you change compiler version, etc. Do not suggest this. It is bad.